# Introspection vs polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, architecture, reflection

I'm wondering how costly C# introspection really is in terms of class type inspection.

Let's say I have a problem,
where in a method of D I have to decide to take an action
depending on the type of different objects `B:A` and `C:A`.

Now I could do this with introspection:

```
public class B: A {}

public class C: A {}

public class D
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        A decisionCause = ...

        if(decisionCause.GetType() == typeof(B)) ReactToB();
        if(decisionCause.GetType() == typeof(C)) ReactToC();
    }
}
```

Is this a violation of the open/closed principle?
Otherwise I could also make `B` and `C` manipulate `D`
and react depending on this manipulation:

```
public class A
{
    public abstract void Manipulate(A manipulating);
}

public class B: A
{
    public override void Manipulate(A manipulating)
    {
        // manipulate in B's way
    }
}


public class C: A
{
    public override void Manipulate(A manipulating)
    {
        // manipulate in C's way
    }
}

public class D
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        if(m_manipulated == valueSetByB) ReactToB();
        if(m_manipulated == valueSetByC) ReactToC();
    }
}
```

However, I don't want these `A` objects to know `class D` at all.

I could even do something like this:

```
class A
{
    public readonly System.Type derivedType;
    A(System.Type derivedType)
    {
        this.derivedType = derivedType;
    }
}

class B: A
{
    B(): base(typeof(B)) {};
}

class C: A
{
    C(): base(typeof(C)) {};
}

public class D
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        A decisionCause = ...

        if(decisionCause.derivedType == typeof(B)) ReactToB();
        if(decisionCause.derivedType == typeof(C)) ReactToC();
    }
}
```

However, I think it is a bad idea to allow type distinction like this,
since the ones extending could do something that was not meant by the one who implemented A.

Is introspection a reasonable way?
Is there another way this could be approached?

Comment: Why does `D` need to react differently?  Can you put that react logic in the `A`-derivative?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a violation of the open/closed principle?

Yes, that's pretty much the canonical example...

> Is introspection a reasonable way?

No. Using reflection to peek into the runtime types like this is smelly to the extreme. Doing manual type checking is a sure fire sign you're doing something improper if you need to resort to that rather than using the more natural tools provided to you by the language.

> Is there another way this could be approached?

Of course. The first, best approach would be to adjust your design so that this sort of thing isn't required. Without knowing what problem you actually face, I can't offer much more advice on that regard.

Another better alternative is to not encode this sort of thing into types. Just have `A`, with some sort of data (or better yet, a delegate/strategy) that differentiates its use. This too can be smelly, but more often is a fine approach to problems where you have "types of A" - far better than inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with responses to your questions posted by Telastyn, so I wont duplicate it. I see that you are trying to solve a problem that is beeing solved by [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). The responsability to know how to react differently is of B or C, not D.  You want to switch on a type, so make it in OO way (You are really close to this in your second snippet):

```
            public interface IReactable
            {
                void React(A instance);
            }

            public class A : IReactable
            {
                public abstract void Manipulate(A manipulating);
            }

            public class B: A
            {
                public override void Manipulate(A manipulating)
                {
                    // manipulate in B's way
                }
                public void React(A reacting)
                {
                    // react in B's way
                }
            }


            public class C: A
            {
                public override void Manipulate(A manipulating)
                {
                    // manipulate in C's way
                }
                public void React(A reacting)
                {
                    // react in C's way
                }
            }

            public class D
            {
                public D(A Ainstance) 
                {
    // Inject the dependency here. 
    // It can be B, C, or any future implementation, 
    // and it wont break the code (O & D from SOLID) 
                   instance = Ainstance;
                }
                private A instance;
                void DoSomething()
                {
    // Core of strategy pattern.
    // The 'instance' implementation should know, how to react. 
                    A decisionCause = something;
                    instance.React(decisionCause);
                }
            }
```

And as Telastyn mentioned, reflection is a big code smell in this case.